# how to use interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface, decoupling

Using C# .NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2010.

Well at the moment I'm looking into de-coupling of Classes and using interfaces.
I've implemented a Solution from another post to test if I could get it working but unfortunately I have never used an interface ever.

So here's the basics of what I have:

Form1:

```
partial class Form1 : InterfacePareto
{
    public string myTest
        {
            get { return herpTxt.Text; }
            set { herpTxt.Text = value; }
        }  
}
```

Interface:

```
interface InterfacePareto
{
    string myTest { get; set; }
}
```

MyWorkingOutClass:

```
Class MyWorkingOutClass
{
    private readonly InterfacePareto pare;

    public MyWorkingOutClass(InterfacePareto pare)
    {
        this.pare = pare;
    }

    private void Testtime()
    {
        string firstName = pare.myTest;
        pare.myTest = firstName + " extra";
    }
}
```

The purpose:

The plan at the moment is to get the text from the forms textbox. Then pass it to the working class. The working class then does whatever calculations etc needed, then passes the result back to the forms textbox.

My question is, is my code along the right tracks. If yes, then what am I missing/doing wrong? Or if anyone thinks this is not the right way of achieving what I need, do they have any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Seems ok. Have you any other problems in this case?

Comment: well all im going to do is proc a button event to get this code started but how do I pass the result back to the text box?  Sounds really silly but my understanding is that nothing will happen other than the original text being displayed.

Comment: Well after `pare.myTest` property is set your textbox should change :) Haven't you tested this already?

Comment: yes sorry, no change, reason is it doesnt seem to use the interface or the working class.

Comment: Everything works fine for me. I'll post my code with just few changes in code

Comment: oh thanks very much, not sure why this the class isn't being used nor the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested code and this works fine for me:

```
public partial class MainForm :Form, InterfacePareto //My main form inheriting Form class and interface
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string myTest
    {
        get { return herpTxt.Text; }
        set { herpTxt.Text = value; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //On button click create MyWorkingOutClass instance and pass MainForms instance
        MyWorkingOutClass mc = new MyWorkingOutClass(this); 
        //After this line text box content will change
        mc.Testtime();
    }
}

//Changed modifier to public
public interface InterfacePareto
{
    string myTest { get; set; }
}

//Changed modifier to public
public class MyWorkingOutClass
{
    private readonly InterfacePareto pare;

    public MyWorkingOutClass(InterfacePareto pare)
    {
        this.pare = pare;
    }

    //Changed modifier to public
    public void Testtime()
    {
        string firstName = pare.myTest;
        pare.myTest = firstName + " extra";
    }
}
```

Comment: annnnd that's why I was getting no result....... I was trying to call the method but it didn't exist, I scratched my head thinking there's some magic thing going on I don't understand so decided a straight call from the form, ofc this doesn't work either but didn't error. And guess what it was?   a sodding private on testtime instead of public..........sometimes I need a slap.  Many thanks for the help and verifying my code +1 to you sir

Comment: You just got a lesson - if you cant see method, first thing you want to do is to check modifier. I learned it :)

Comment: yes instead of panicking like a wally! many thanks,  im going to use this to run a query and return a dataset.  quick question,  using this as a foundation it should work?  or is there any little additions when using datasets?

Comment: what I mean is pass text to the working class use them as parameters in the sql query, do the calcualtions and return a dateset to a datgridview on my form

Comment: Yes this should work. :) Just pass collection of data to your working class, create parameters, execute query, get data and set it to interface property, which will set to appropriate data grid.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine.

There is one issue you will get when the MyWorkingOutClass does its work on a different thread than the UI thread.

To solve that you might want to change the implementation on the form to switch to the UI thread.

Comment: well all im going to do is proc a button event to get this code started but how do I pass the result back to the text box? Sounds really silly but my understanding is that nothing will happen other than the original text being displayed.   @youranswer - would using tasks be better than using a new thread in that case? or is there pretty much no difference?

Comment: For this there is no difference between Thread and Task. In C# 5 using async and await will make it a cleaner to code.